# How to export your database after you make some queries in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm new in  mysql workbench properties. so here is the situation
i have 2 tables, 'student' and 'classes'. a student can have multiple classes with student ID as the connected field. one to many relationship. i wrote some queries that connects the two table (i.e using join,...) and i want to export what i have on my queries rather than the two tables (which i got from data export wizard).

i've tried to export to csv file using codes but came across the error 1290

```
select  teacher.student.U_id,  teacher.student.U_id, teacher.student.F_name, teacher.student.L_name
teacher.classess.days,teacher.classess.mor, teacher.classess.aft
from teacher.student, teacher.classesss
where teacher.student.U_id=teacher.classess.U_id
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Eddie Vu\Downloads' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

i expect the output to be store in a csv file.
please help, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your command, if it worked, would create the file on the server machine. But probably that directory doesn't exist or MySQL isn't allowed to write to it or it is configured not to do so.

But I suppose you want to export to a file on the client machine.

Note the section "Export/Import" in the little toolbar above the result grid and the little button with a disk in front of a grid.

[image]

If you click that button a dialog opens that allows you to save the current result in the grid to a file.